# Unable to properly install mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql

So i want to write a python program to connect to mysql database.
I am using PyCharm for that.
Now i have properly install mysql-connector using the pip command.

But PyCharm cannot pick up the my mysql library.

Here are some screenshots and terminal

[PyCharm library problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vQcMD.png)

[Terminal Window to install mysql connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dQOKZ.png)

What should i do to make it work properly ?
(I am using MacOs Mojave and Python 3.6.7 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit))

Comment: Check what interpreter your are using: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html

Comment: It is set to Python 3.7

Comment: You'll want to check that it's the same interpreter that you are pip installing mysql-connector on

Comment: Yes got it ! Thanks. My mac had various versions of python installed

Answer (score 0):

Install mysql-connector on the interpreter you are using in PyCharm.